# Advanced trigger with SELECT inside CASE instruction

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing trigger and depending on data inserted, I want to compare the input of data to select.
I have 3 columns col1, col2 and col3 (only one of them can be not null). When I insert data to table, I want to check if data joined to that column is correct.

I tried `CASE` but it didn't work.

```sql
CASE
    WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN SELECT * FROM XXX
    WHEN col2 IS NOT NULL THEN SELECT * FROM YYY
    WHEN col3 IS NOT NULL THEN SELECT * FROM ZZZ LEFT JOIN aaa ON col3.id=aaa.id
    ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: *"I'm doing trigger and depend on data inserted i want to compare imput data to select. I have 3 columns col1, col2 and col3 "*    Using a [VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) instead sounds more sensable to do to get that selection on runtime..

Comment: can we see the full code for the trigger, as well as the design of all tables involved to better understand and problem shoot this issue?

Comment: I have not ended it, for now it only checks if records already exist in DB. In basic, at the begining I want to have select with data i could compare with NEW record. I want to check with trigger if user have permision to lower level when i want to gran him higher rights. I store levels of permision in record (only  one column can be difrent from null) and permisions are inherited to down (like in file and folders in system)

Comment: A case statement can only return 1 value - you cannot use a select.